# Normalizer of cyclic subgroup of $S_5$

Tags: group-theory

> In $S_5$, consider $\langle \sigma \rangle = \langle (12)(345) \rangle$. Find the normalizer of $\langle g \rangle$ in $S_5$.

Since $\langle \sigma \rangle$ is cyclic, it is abelian, so its normalizer equales its centralizer, and the center of $S_5$ is a subgroup of the centralizer. I can therefore state that
$$Z(S_5) \leq C_{S_5} (\langle \sigma \rangle) = N_{S_5} (\langle \sigma \rangle) \leq S_5$$
and that
$$\langle \sigma \rangle \leq N_{S_5} (\langle \sigma \rangle).$$
By Lagrange's theorem, I have that $6$ divides the order of the normalizer and that the normalizer divides $120$, the order of $S_5$. So the order is some positive integer multiple of $6$. The only elements that are obviously in it are the identity (the center of $S_5$), $(12)(345)$ itself, and its inverse. Is there a way to find the normalizer other than brute force?

Comment: Reading through that answer is helpful, but I am still quite stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A couple comments first:

> Since ⟨σ⟩ is cyclic, it is abelian, so its normalizer equales its centralizer

This is false. For instance consider a nontrivial cyclic subgroup of a dihedral group; the reflections normalize the cyclic subgroup but are not in its centralizer.

> the center of S5 is a subgroup of the centralizer

This is a good observation in general, but useless here since $Z(S_5)$ is trivial.

---

Now let's let $H=\langle\sigma\rangle$ and $N=N_{S_5}(H)$ and $C=C_{S_5}(H)$.

The cyclic group $H\cong\mathbb{Z}_6$ has two generators, $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$. Therefore, any $n\in\ N$ either swaps these or fixes them. That is, we have a homomorphism $N\to\mathbb{Z}_2$. The kernel is $C$ (why?), so if we can find any element $g\in N\setminus C$ we will know that $N=C\sqcup gC$ by Lagrange's theorem (why?).

I will let you exhibit a $g\in S_5$ for which $g\sigma g^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}$, in which case $g\in N\setminus C$. You will need to know how conjugation-by-$g$ affects a permutation $\sigma$'s cycle notation; are you familiar with that? You will also need to determine $C$. Show any $\tau\in C$ must preserve the sets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$ and do a little more work to show the centralizer is simply $C=\langle(12),(345)\rangle=\langle (12)(345)\rangle$.